# How do I protect an electronic circuit

Tags: circuit-protection

I’m beginner in electronics and i have project for grow LED light and i want to connect LED with timer. My inquire how I protect my circuit.
My circuit

Adapter 
12V 1.2A

Timer 
(5-20v) up to 5A

2 * LED CHIP 
(6.6V 0.300A) 2W
One led (3.3V 0.300A 1W) i will conect series.

I want be sure 6.6 V will be arrive to LED chip not more to damage my LED
I’m waiting for your recommendation.

Thank you

---

Is this circuit correct ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDSq7p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: With LEDs you should not look at the voltage so much, instead you want the **current** to be correct. So you do not want 6.6 V, you want **300 mA**. Browse this site and search for "LED resistor" to learn how to calculate the proper series resistor. Put the specifications of the power supply and LEDs on **separate** lines because as it is now it is confusing. Also include a **schematic** of how you intend to connect everything.

Comment: You can use a zener diode in parallel to your input. Maybe if you show your schematics it would be clearer to indicate where

Comment: I concur with Bimpelrekkie with the added suggestion that you drive the LEDs with current sources (LEDs are current controlled and their forward voltage can vary quite a lot over manufacturing variations quite apart from temperature).

Answer (score 1):

Simple Ohm’s Law solution  duplicated many times in this EE forum.

(V drop) / If = Rs

(12 - 9.9 )/0.3A= 7 Ohms

Pd=V drop * If  = 2.1* 0.3A = 0.63W so to reduce 100’C temp rise use 2W part or two 1W 14 ohm parts in parallel or 8 * 1/4W resistors in parallel , each 8x 7 Ohms =56 Ohms 1/4W

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyIw4H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Must be the guy with a grudge again - the silent critic -1

Comment: Thank you for reply. I will contact the LED by series way as i know the total for 2 LED will be 6.6v 0.3A.

Comment: R=(12-3.3-3.3)/0.3=18 ohms, should be use 18R 2W

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your configuration. Yes correct but inefficient. If the R is rated for 2W at 25’C and dumps 5.4^2/18=1.6W what temp rise above ambient do you expect ? 1.6/2*100? Are you cool with that?

Comment: No, I will use it in room temperature. Are you recomend to conected in parallel as you mentioned.

Comment: I suggested options , you pick.  but always derate power capacity to run cooler as I explained.